# facebook custom story questions, how to get user typed text into the custom story

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to make a custom story for a web application.  The story should go something like this "(User) got a ride from (license plate) using (app name)"

Here is the HTML markup -

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="LicensePlate"><em> * </em>License
              Plate: </label> <input name="LicensePlate" id="LicensePlate" value=""
              required="true" type="text"> </div>
```

I want to take the user entered license plate number and have it show up in the custom story. How do I do this? Do I simply configure the url in  the Meta tags below? I have not been able to do this.

I am also unsure if I need to add the code from the story, action type and custom object for the fb.api calls. Are all 3 of them necessary in this scenario?

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxx" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="testapp:license_plate" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://example.com/LicensePlate" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="LicensePlate" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```